# Send request has two type parameters (Query, Multipart/form-data)

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio, retrofit

I have been tyring to execute API has two parameters as I said in title
here is my API configure

```
//region SignUp
String SIGN_UP_USER = "User/SignUp";

@POST(SIGN_UP_USER)
@Multipart
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
Call<SignUpResponse> signUp(
        @Part MultipartBody.Part profilePicture,
        @Query("email") String email,
        @Query("password") String password,
        @Query("firstName") String firstName,
        @Query("lastName") String lastName);
//endregion
```

But when I execute the request I got this error:
**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multipart body must have at least one part.**

And here is the details of request from Swagger
[image]

Any suggestions for this issue,
**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Please share code snippet on how you are creating instance of `MultipartBody.Part`

Comment: Here is how i create an instance but I didn't initialise it (cause I want to send it empty)
**MultipartBody.Part profilePicture;**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All what I did to fix my problem was remove this Annotation

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
```

from my code and request.
and for sending empty files you can just send a null parameter for file will take it as empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Part("email") RequestBody email,` rather than `@Query` .

```
@POST(SIGN_UP_USER)
@Multipart
Call<SignUpResponse> signUp(
        @Part MultipartBody.Part profilePicture,
        @Part("email") RequestBody email,
        @Part("password") RequestBody password,
        @Part("firstName") RequestBody firstName,
        @Part("lastName") RequestBody lastName);

RequestBody email= requestBody1.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "email@email.com");
```

Comment: I tried it but also didn't work

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could show me how you call.

Comment: Here is my change on configuring API (I removed the the the @ from annotation cause stack over flow take it as mention)

    //region SignUp
    String SIGN_UP_USER = "User/SignUp";

    POST(SIGN_UP_USER)
    Multipart
    Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    Call<SignUpResponse> signUp(
            Part MultipartBody.Part profilePicture,
            Part("email") RequestBody email,
            Part("password") RequestBody password,
            Part("firstName") RequestBody firstName,
            Part("lastName") RequestBody lastName);
    //endregion

Comment: and here is where i init the instance I send it 

`MultipartBody.Part profilePicture = null;
            RequestBody emailRequestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), emailSignup);
            RequestBody passwordRequestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), passwordSignUp);
            RequestBody firstNameRequestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), firstNameSignUp);
            RequestBody lastNameRequestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), lastNameSignUp); `

Comment: Below is an example of using a multipartBody

`File fileToUpload;

RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(mimeType), fileToUpload); (it would be good if you use ProgressRequestBody)

MultipartBody.Part fileToUploadPart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("attachments", fileToUpload.getName(), requestBody);
`

Comment: What if i wouldn't send file should I fill it with Null?

Comment: The parameter can be set to 'null' if you wish

Answer (score 0):

Try the below way. [I'm using Kotlin].

1. Create Multipart Body Object

   ```
            val signUpBuilder = MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            signUpBuilder.addFormDataPart("email",email)
            signUpBuilder.addFormDataPart("password",password)
            signUpBuilder.addFormDataPart("firstName",firstName)
            signUpBuilder.addFormDataPart("lastName",lastName)
            signUpBuilder.addFormDataPart("profilePicture","filename.jpg",file)
            signUpBuilder.build()
   ```
2. Pass the builder to your signup method.

Do not use multipart annotation.

```
@POST(SIGN_UP_USER)
fun signUp(
    @Body requestBody: MultipartBody
): Call<SignUpResponse>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I tried your solution but in my case I want send empty file, how can I do that any suggestions :(

Comment: @mustafahasria - what do you mean by empty file? Please elaborate

Comment: I mean sometimes I don't want to send a profile picture file

Comment: simple check file is empty or not before add parameter.